# func removing(Element) -> [T] {} on collection in swift

Tags: swift

If you have a collection type in Swift (like a `Set<T>`) then you can remove something from the set like...

```
var s = // some set
s.remove(someElement)
```

and it will mutate s and remove the `someElement` from it.

However, this is a mutating function.

Is there a non-mutating function that would return a new set? Like...

```
let smallerSet = largerSet.removing(someElement)
```

I could use `filter` but then it turns this from a `O(1)` into an `O(n)` time problem.

If there isn't one already I can write one myself. Is there a convention for the name of a non-mutating function like this?

Comment: It will always be O(n) since you are going to copy the set...

Comment: Will NSMutableSet help https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsmutableset? I have seen mixed results with it specially for adding/searching but delete is faster. Not sure about your use case but worth a read.

Comment: @kennytm ah yeah, that's a good point. I hadn't thought of that. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use subtracting function of the Set. For that you need to put that element to be deleted in another Set.

```
let elementToBeDeleted = Set(arrayLiteral: 1)
var wholeSet = Set(arrayLiteral: 1,2,3)
wholeSet = wholeSet.subtracting(element)
print(wholeSet) //This would print [2,3].
```

Hope this what you need to get things done.

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely the closest to what I was looking for and it's "out of the box" too. :D

Comment: There's no need to use the `init(xyzLiteral:)` initialisers – they're used by the compiler when you use a literal, for example `var wholeSet: Set = [1, 2, 3]` & `wholeSet.subtracting([1])`.

Comment: @Fogmeister Glad it helped you in any sort.

Comment: @Hamish.Yes you can initialise in any way.